# SQL statement to find (and remove) duplicate users

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to clean up a database for an email newsletter. There are 2 main tables, subscribers and lists.

This query will give me every user that is mentioned more than once.

```
SELECT name, email, list, count(*)
FROM `subscribers`
GROUP BY email
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

What I want to do is delete any user in list 7 that is also in another list. Should be pretty straight forward, but my SQL skills are a bit rusty. Any ideas? Thanks.

Clarification:

```
+---+-----------------------+------+
| id|         email         | list |
+---+-----------------------+------+
| 1 | name@gmail.com        |    3 |
| 2 | othername@hotmail.com |    2 |
| 3 | othername@hotmail.com |    7 |
+---+-----------------------+------+
```

id 3 would be the one I want to find and delete in this case.

Comment: What is list 7? So you want to delete this user from both tables, right?

Comment: List 7 look like a typo, I think he meant in list **&** that is also in another list

Comment: No, list 7. There's a bunch of lists. If a row contains list = 7, but if that user is in another list as well, remove the entry that says list = 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty much exactly what you said, in English, sort of translated into SQL ...

```
delete subscribers s                     -- delete any user
where list = list7                       -- in List 7
   and exists(Select * from subscribers  -- that is also in another list
              where email = s.email  
                 and list <> list7)
```

if you want the user deleted completely, but only if he is in List 7 and in some other list, then you should have phrased the question like that.

"*What I want to do is delete any user who is in  list 7 and is also in any other list*."

if that is indeed what you want then, again, write the delete statement to read the same way...

```
delete subscribers s                     -- delete any user
where exists (Select * from subscribers  -- who is in List 7
              where email = s.email  
                 and list = list7) 
   and exists(Select * from subscribers  -- and is also in another list
              where email = s.email  
                 and list <> list7)
```

to test what the resukts will be, before you run the delete, either do this...

```
Begin Transaction
delete subscribers s                     -- delete any user
where list = list7                       -- in List 7
   and exists(Select * from subscribers  -- that is also in another list
              where email = s.email  
                 and list <> list7)
Select * from subscribers
```

... Then, if it looks ok, run
    `Commit Transaction`

.. or if it does not, run
    `Rollback Transaction`

If you are not comfortable with Transactions, then run this..

```
Select * from subscribers s              -- show me the users
where list = list7                       -- in List 7
   and exists(Select * from subscribers  -- that are also in another list
              where email = s.email  
                 and list <> list7)
```

Comment: I think he wants to delete the user from all lists and not the the user in the list7

Comment: Thanks. How can I do a test for the results? Changing your DELETE for SELECT gives me a SQL syntax error.

Comment: `select * from subscribers where...`

Comment: @Nizam That returns all the users in list 7. I only want the ones that are already in other lists.

Comment: That returns what would be deleted (to test before the deletion), which was your question.

Comment: To select the opposite you should use: `select * from subscribers s                     where list <> list7
   and not exists(Select * from subscribers
              where email = s.email  
                 and list = list7)`